# How do I block certain websites with my Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, blocking

I'm making a simple chrome extension for a project. I am making an extension that blocks certain URL's(social media etc) to make studying more efficient. I'm not very good in JS but I want to learn. I had some ideas that maybe it could either block the website or just draw something in a div blocking its content. Also, maybe I could input an URL into popup.html to specify the blocked website. Saving data in firebase. Also, I read that maybe its easier to use declarativeWebRequest but not quite sure how to use it.

Manifest.js

```
"name": "StudyBuddy",
"description": "Helps you study by blocking distracting websites",
"version": "2.0",
 "permissions": [
   "webRequestBlocking",
   "webRequest",
   "activeTab",
   "tabs",
   "http://*/*",
   "https://*/*"
],
 "content_scripts" : [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js" : ["background.js"],
    "css" : ["styles.css"]



  }],
 "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Blocks websites",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"

  },
  "manifest_version": 2
```

background.js

```
console.log("Loaded extension");


function blockRequest(details) {
   return {cancel: true};
}

function updateFilters(urls) {
   if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(blockRequest))
     chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blockRequest);
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockRequest, {urls: ["*://*.facebook.com/*", "*://*.facebook.net/*"]}, ['blocking']);
```

}

At the moment my extension doesnt block anything.

Comment: Silly question, but do you actually call the `updateFilters` method anywhere? All you've shown is defining it.

Comment: Not a silly question. But no, I'm not calling it anywhere atm, i don't really understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, your code has two issues :

- Your manifest.json didn't specify `background.js`, so that code wasn't running.
- You didn't actually call the `updateFilters` function from anywhere.

I corrected both those issues and this extension works fine for me, it blocks Facebook as expected.

In general I suggest you do some more reading of the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) for extensions as you try to get started, especially the parts on [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

manifest.json: (note that I don't have access to your popup html/css so I had to remove that section from the manifest).

```
{
  "name": "StudyBuddy",
  "description": "Helps you study by blocking distracting websites",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
     "webRequestBlocking",
     "webRequest",
     "activeTab",
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
  ],
  "background" : {
    "scripts":  [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
console.log("Loaded extension");


function blockRequest(details) {
   return {cancel: true};
}

function updateFilters(urls) {
   if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(blockRequest))
     chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blockRequest);
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockRequest, {urls: ["*://*.facebook.com/*", "*://*.facebook.net/*"]}, ['blocking']);
}

updateFilters();
```

Comment: Thank you fort answering. I added it but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Doughnut Ok, your extension had another issue. I cleaned up the code and got it working for me, see my edited answer.

Comment: Embarrassing. Thank you very much, I got the extension to work now. Although, odd is that if I add websites it doesn't block them.

     `{urls: ["*://*.facebook.com/*", "*://*.facebook.net/*", "*://*.reddit.com/*", "*://*.reddit.net*"]}, ['blocking']); `

Comment: You have to reload the extension for any changes to take effect. Hit refresh on the `chrome://extensions` page or click the `Reload` option displayed on that page under your extension. You should also use `Inspect views: background page` on that page to look at the console for the extension, it will show you if there are any errors, and it's where the output from `console.log` is displayed.

Comment: I reloaded it many times and  now it doesn't even block FB no more. It doesn't even log it in the console anymore. I also did changes to popup.html and that worked.

Comment: You may have to post another question then, comments are not the place for extended debugging. In the meantime if my answer solved the problem in your original question, please mark it as accepted.