# Chrome extension: block custom websites not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried the code from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889727/how-do-i-block-certain-websites-with-my-chrome-extension) to block certain websites:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "StudyBuddy",
  "description": "Helps you study by blocking distracting websites",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
     "webRequestBlocking",
     "webRequest",
     "activeTab",
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
  ],
  "background" : {
    "scripts":  [
      "background.js",
       "persistent": true
    ]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Background.js:

```
console.log("Loaded extension");


function blockRequest(details) {
   return {cancel: true};
}

function updateFilters(urls) {
   if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(blockRequest))
     chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blockRequest);
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockRequest, {urls: ["*://blank.org/"] }, ['blocking']);
}

updateFilters();
```

I don't get any error but I can easily access blank.org despite the code.

Comment: What did you try to solve this on your own?

Comment: The code blocks only the home page of blank.org so you may want to add `*` after the last `/`. And make sure you reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page after changing manifest.json or the background script.

Comment: yeah adding * didn't do it either. I tried looking for docs but couldn't find any :(

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest